# Linker errors when adding opencv library to windows form application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++

I am trying to do opencv operations through images obtained by GUI or windows form application.

So, I added all the opencv libraries to the application. It runs perfectly fine without including opencv library but not so when I include.

When I included the opencv library (**#include"opencv\cv.h"**) as follows,

```
//MyForm.h
#pragma once
#include"opencv\cv.h"
namespace Project3 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;

..... }
```

then the compiler throwed more errors and all of them denoted to unresolved externals.

```
 Error  14  error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
```

If my way of adding opencv library to a GUI is not compatible, Please suggest some alternative

Comment: try #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

Comment: @GPPK: They are working. I think, all other opencv includes are working except, cv.h. But one needs cv.h library to do image processing. Right ?

Comment: look at this tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#smoothing

Comment: apart from above, please show, which opencv *libraries* you *link*. (you probably need at least opencv_core249.lib,opencv_imgproc249.lib,opencv_highgui249.lib

Comment: @berak: I was just setting up the opencv with GUI. So, I didn't know what other libraries I require and I started with a cv.h library.

Comment: ^^ that's a *header* file (compiling), not a library(linking) the error is about missing libs, not the wrong headers.

Comment: @berak: You are right. I had already added some libraries to the linker such as opencv_core.lib, opencv_highgui.lib, opencv_imgproc.lib and opencv_calib3d.lib. I was getting the same error. Then I found I must also add opencv_objdetect.lib. When I added that, all the errors were gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately

```
#include"opencv\cv.h"
```

is not really the correct way of including the OpenCV header files. If you look at some of the tutorials ([Here is one for Image Processing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#smoothing)) it shows that you only need to include the header files that you required.

So, for your particular instance you are eventually going to use the image processing code, I would suggest editing your code to this:

```
//MyForm.h
#pragma once
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
namespace Project3 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;

..... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. The problem is that for the header

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
```

I didn't add the library **opencv_objdetect248.lib** to the linker, which I didn't expect to be required. Ofcourse, I have added other libraries to the linker, but not this one. That's why around 12 errors popped up. After adding, the build was succeeded.